# Bundler showing Install GIT error even when all the Gems are bundled in vendor folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, bundler

We deployed the application into a Test environment with all the Gems already available in vendor/ folder. But when we run the following command, we get GIT not installed error.

```
$ bundle list
You need to install git to be able to use gems from git repositories. For help installing git, please refer to GitHub's tutorial at https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git
```

Versions of ruby and bundler we are using:

```
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.6.1
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24 revision 45159)
```

As you can see below, bundle is already frozen and we ensured that the gems depending on Git are available in the vendor/ folder.

```
$ cat .bundle/config
---
BUNDLE_FROZEN: '1'
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
BUNDLE_BIN: bin
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
```

Has anyone seen this error before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest trying an upgrade to Bundler v1.6.2, as a similar issue was fixed around this.

Issue: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2977

Merged pull request: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/2973